# How to load image from binary data in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am a beginner in .net Technology. I am  using VS2008, C# ,Asp.Net 3.5 Framework, SQL SERVER 2005. In a database table 'Cust_M_Tbl', there is a  field of varchar(500) type viz Cust_Image. The value in the Cust_Image is

```
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
```

I want to display this customer image in my web page. How can I do it? Should I decrypt it? or it is in any other format? Any help will be appreciated. Regards,

Comment: What have you tried? By the way you shouldn't post customers image source it can hold personal information.

Comment: @Reniuz....its an edited one just used for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decoding as  @Christophe Geers suggested
use

```
string encodedString = "your image data encoded as base 64 char array";
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);

Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

maybe this can help more:
http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You can find an online decoder here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

It validates your input as a valid Base-64 char array.

You can decode a base64 string in C# in the following way:

```
string encodedString = "your image data encoded as base 64 char array";
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
```

Take a look at the [FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) article on MSDN for more information.

Now you want to display the image on an ASP.NET web page (*.ASPX).

E.g.:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" />
```

Instead of referencing an actual image file (eg: myimage.jpg), you want to reference an ASP.NET handler (*.ASHX) that serves the bytes of the image (the byte[] array named data in the previous code sample).

E.g.:

```
<img src="ImageHandler.ashx" />
```

The code for the image handler looks something like this:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Load the image (see previous code sample)
        byte[] data = ...;

        // Display the image
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
    }
}
```

[Read more about implementing an IHttpHandler on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx).

You need to pass an identifier to the imagehandler.ashx page so that you know which image to retrieved.

E.g.:

```
<img src="ImageHandler.ashx?id=<%=id%>" />
```

Put this instead of your img-tag or your ASP.NET image control.

Comment: though it is a first step it does not really explain how to display the image

Comment: @Christophe Geers....I got this error- Error 2 The name 'Encoding' does not exist in the current context. How can I load this data to my img control?

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to hold the byte[] in a string ? why ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade...I am not so particular of that...i just need to display the image As Cristophe suggested I used the following code-          string encodedString = c.dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
            string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Comment: @Christophe Geers....I got the decodedString.Thanks Cristophe....But how can I connect it with my image control

Comment: @ChristopheGeers...Let me check it

Comment: @ChristopheGeers....It is an asp.net image-                  <tr><td align="center">
                <asp:Image ID="Img1" runat="server"  Width ="100px" Height="111px" /> </td></tr>   Where should I put <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?id=<%=id%>" 
?

Comment: Remove the <asp:Image ... /> control and put the image handler in its place.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers...sorry...i didn't get you..please explain

Comment: I'm sorry, the comment system is not a chat box. I'll update my answer one last time.