# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when converting

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

My code is:

```
Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
```

---

```
public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "select Cust_Image from Cust_M_Tbl  where Cust_FID = '"+empno+"'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            try
            {

                return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);    ////Exception generated here

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

    }
```

I am using VS2008, C#, ASP.NET 3.5 Framework, SQL Server 2005. 
Any help will be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: which line is throwing this exception?

Comment: What is the SQL Server datatype of the Cust_Image field?

Comment: Did you ran the query on management studio? It seems that it has no results.

Comment: Does a row exist in the database for the specified empno?

Comment: You should get into the habit of using [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). In this specific case you are not open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but it is a good habit to have, as other code might not be safe.

Comment: what does `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` return?

Comment: The empno parameter you passed to the sql query is returning null for the Cust_IMage value, or may be that empno doesnt exist in the database. Check for null equality before converting to byte.

Comment: @Vijay...value is in the table ...am getting the value in img also....the problem is Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: What kind of data is contained in these strings? As the error says, System.String can't be cast to a byte array. Is it a URL or file path to an image?

Comment: @IanNelson....the datafield is of varchar type.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load image from binary data in Asp.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471197/how-to-load-image-from-binary-data-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Ok many tries to help you but the problem is unspecified in question. From [previous your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8471197/754438) I can tell that problem is - field `Cust_Image` is varchar and you trying to convert it to binary.

So solution should be something like this:

```
return new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(img.ToString()));
```

Comment: Well, that would have been nice to know :-)

Comment: @Reniuz.. Cust_Image field is of varchar type.....unfortunately i am in charge of this project from today.somebody has already did all database designning and other things earlier.so when i run the project i got this error. how to rectify it?

Comment: @IanNelson yeah I read the other question earlier today and saw that the meber name was the same, which is why I posted about the other question

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
```

use this line as:

```
string conn = string.Empty;
if(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"] != null)
{
    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;
}
```

if you don't set the dbcon key in your app.config file, you can't access ConnectionString property as ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"] will give you null.

Scenario 2:

```
object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Check whether the img object is null before using it in the code.

Comment: @Azhar....I have checked both....all r right..i have set dbcon in webconfig....img is not null it has values

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if no row exists in the database for the specified employee number.

We need to check for this before casting the result to a byte array.

Try this:

```
public static string ConnectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString;

public Stream ShowEmployeeImage(int employeeNumber)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        const string query = 
            "select Cust_Image from Cust_M_Tbl where Cust_FID = '@empNo'";

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empNo", employeeNumber.ToString());
            conn.Open();

            var image = command.ExecuteScalar();

            return image == null ? null : new MemoryStream((byte[]) image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ian.....i get the value of image...but the problem generates when it return the value.

Comment: What does the value look like? It is a byte array, or something else?

Comment: it's a base64 string (see my answer for a link to previous post from OP)